# Promise resolves earlier than expected and not returning an AXIOS call value

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, axios

I'm making a request to a service that generates several strings in rapid succession. My problem arise from having to return a promise with this service, as I do not control the service process that returns the string.

I want to emphasize the fact that I necessarily need to return a promise.

Right now, what I have is the main function (handler.ts) and it doesn't mantain any business logic, including only the following:

```
public static callback: any;

public static async init(configuration, callback): Promise<any> {
     this.callback = callback;
     ...
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const result = await Service.bootstrap(configuration)
            return resolve(result)
        } catch(err) {
            reject(err)
        }
     }
}
```

This handler calls the service, which has the bootstrap function that performs a call to a .js file that obtains some information from my computer and then returns a string about it.

```
import loadComputerInformation from 'load.js'

public async bootstrap() : Promise<any> {
      loadComputerInformation();

      function useComputerInfoString() {
            // window.getInfo is generated by loadComputerInformation(), and I can not control 
            // when does it return it, as it generates several strings with rapid succession 
            // and until the function exists, I will not get my string.
            if (typeof window.getInfo !== 'function') {return;}
            const data = window.getInfo();
            if (data.finished) {
              clearTimeout(timeoutId);
              const infoString = data.computerInfo;
              Service.axiosCall(infoString);
            }
          }
          // I have to set an interval to perform the call several times, and until it resolves it
          // it will not stop performing this call.
          const timeoutId = setInterval(useComputerInfoString, 500);
   }
   return;
}
```

Therefore, the problem that I'm facing is that my promise gets lost in another thread, and I can not return the value from **Service.axiosCall(infoString)**, which is just a standard axios call, but that necessarily needs the **infoString**.

Adding the axios call function just in case it is useful. Right now, I'm using the callback passed to the handler.js to return the axios call, but I want to be able to include it in the Promise without the necessity of a callback function

```
public static async axiosCall(blackbox): Promise<any> {
   await axios.post('https://somecall.com/info', blackbox)
    .then((response) => {  this.callback(element)
                           return element);
     }
}
```

Any idea of how to solve this?

**Highlight**

Please note that loadComputerInformation() asynchronously loads Window.getInfo(), but it does not resolve only one value, but several, therefore I can not await on Window.getInfo() because at the beggining it does not exist, and will only return **undefined**

Also, right now, the code is up and running, but the way it is returning the value is with the callback and not as a promise.

Comment: The `return` statement in the `init` function can (and I suggest should) be replaced by `return Service.bootstrap(configuration)` - Using a promise to resolve a promise to return from an `async` function which returned a promise is overkill :)

Comment: The promise constructor function isn't even `async` so that is also wrong but you should just return the promise instead of wrapping it. You are hitting TDZ on your `useComputerInfoString` as well. You can't use `timeoutId` before being initialized by the `const` declaration.

Comment: But importantly, the `bootstrap` function synchronously returns undefined when first called. The inherent problem seems to be that at no stage is polling the value returned by  `window.getInfo();` turned into a promise resolved when `data.finished` is set. Attempting to fix it (as a reader) fails because the is no information in the post about the  `useBlackboxString` function.  Promisifying the `window.getInfo()` polling is your next step.

Comment: your `init` function won't run - you should see errors

Comment: You need to place the `new Promise` *inside* the `bootstrap` method. Currently, your `bootstrap` method doesn't `return` anything, so there is nothing your other code could `await`

Comment: Hello @traktor, I just corrected the code, useBlackboxString is supposed to be useComputerInfoString()

Comment: the `bootstrap` function returns immediately. Which in turn resolves the promise that relies on it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `bootstrap` function whose returned promise resolves with the **response** returned from an axios call.

This suggestion (based on information in the post) is vanilla JavaScript to demonstrate how to the problem might be approached. Obviously modification to integrate it into the application will be needed:

```
 const bootstrap = () => new Promise( resolve => {
    loadComputerInformation();
    let state = "load";
    const timer = setInterval( ()=> {
       if( state == "load") {
           if( typeof window.getData != "function") {
                return;
           }
           state = "get";
       }
       let data;
       if( state == "get") {
           data = window.getData();
           if(!data.finished) {
               return;
           }
           // state = "request";
       }
       clearInterval(timer);
       resolve( axios('post', "https:example.com/info", data.computerInfo) );

    }, 100); // 1/10th second?
};
```

Note this answer has been modified to use a state machine to wait for `getData` to be loaded asynchronously, then to wait for a call to `getData` to return a data object with a `finished` property, before resolving the promise returned with the promise returned by the `axios` call - the first answer was simpler right up until it needed to wait for `getData` code to be loaded asynchronously.

Beneath the question lies a problem that may have to be written off to code debt:  JavaScript is event driven. `loadComputerInformation` appears to have been written for its results to be polled. It is hard to imagine a justifiable reason why it was left in that state.

Comment: Thank you! Between a fail mixture of return statements and the `poll` context that you gave me, I was able to catch my error. Now I successfully return a promise!